# Flooding space tunnels to trap some characters!

Tags: geography, terraforming, underground, flash-floods

Humans have terraformed another planet; part of how they have done so involves utilizing (and building new) caves and tunnels (could be lava tubes, or could be another planet which has something similar, I'm flexible on this). They have energy and can grow things with solar power - a combination of solar panels and windows with filters on close-to-surface-level rooms.

I need a slow, continuous, and unexpected flood of the tunnels to eventually trap and kill some characters. I'd like the characters to be able to escape for a little while, but reach a point where it is fairly obvious that they won't make it out.

How do I make this happen - as in, what might break and leave the characters with a choice between drowning in the tunnels and walking into an uninhabitable atmosphere? What secondary considerations might I need to think about with flooding a series of tunnels?

(hoping this question isn't too broad!)

Comment: We're not a site for open ended questions with many equally valid answers. That means questions seeking to brainstorm or generate ideas like this one are a poor fit for this site. Unlike a lot of other QA sites we're pretty strict not just about the topic of the question but the type of question that is asked. You can learn more about this by taking the [tour] and visiting the [help].

Comment: Hi @E.Delaney. Please remember that world rules are independent of stories. In other words, we can help you create your world's geology, which might includes lakes. We can help you design a reservoir, etc. based on your world's technology and resources. but per the [help/on-topic], we don't help tell stories. You'll note on that page that it also says we're not fond of brainstorming questions. If you're tempted to ask an "I need some ideas!" question, there's a 99.9% chance you're asking either the wrong question or asking it in the wrong place. Also, only one question per post, please.

Answer (score 1):

Have them dig into a water table/reservoir which first floods their digging machinery so they can't plug it. Then since it wasn't expected they don't have bulkheads just doors that can't withstand the water pressure for long.

So they keep retreating from the flooded areas but can't stem the leaks.

It would have to be a large body of water then gravity would handle the rest. Perhaps they've broken into a water chamber that opens into the sea or a lake.